# React Native Azure AD authentication custom Login screen | azure api management

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-ad-b2c

please help me to create a react native login screen with the use of Azure AD :

I want to create a register/login screen in react-native (email,password) and want the authentication to be done by Azure AD, (I'm a beginner with Azure AD).

I know we can authenticate the user with Azure AD but I'm not able to understand the clear idea and structure of Apis.

what I want is to first register any user through the react-native register screen and in backend APIs in DB I will store the email and hashed password.

but for the JWT token and Refresh token I want to use the Azure AD.

So while doing the login in my custom login screen user will enter their email, and password which I will send to Azure Ad to authenticate and will receive the JWT token.

After that, I want to use this JWT token to pass with other backend APIs (API management) so that the JWT token can also be verified.

Please share any relevant doc or any tutorial that I can follow OR is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD will issue tokens for work, student and personal accounts but not for custom users stored in a DB. You can use the DB to augment data related to Azure AD users though.

To enable Azure AD authentication in React native you will need [react-native-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-msal). Authentication will be done through Azure AD UI. If you want to user your own login form, you will need to implement the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) which is not recommended and does lack some features like personal accounts, passwordless sign-ins or MFA support.

To register/create users in Azure AD you can consume the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0) trough [@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client)